# What is the "best practices" approach to setting up custom global email defaults in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment, actionmailer

I'm starting a new Rails 3 app from scratch.

And as I was going through basic setup ( configuring gems, sessions, etc) I ran into something that has been nagging me for a while.

Our current system ( a mixture of Ruby scripts & Rails 2 app) send various email / fax notifications to clients. There are certain things that are common in 80% of cases - cc - certain email accounts on our end and email signature.

Previously I just defined GLOBALS in the environment.rb  such as

```
SYSTEM_EMAIL_SIGNATURE
```

or

```
SYSTEM_EMAIL_NOTIFY
```

and used them later in mailers or if it was a stand-alone script I had a setup.rb file - that had a bunch of common settings - including a has with custom email settings like this.

Since I'm rebuilding this app from scratch and consolidating all scripts into one ruby app - I was trying to think of a better way to do this.

Right now I'm setting up an email.rb Initializer that has action_mailer settings, that I extended by adding a few more items:

```
      ########## Setup Global Email Defaults ##############
Site::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method   = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'mail.example.com',
    :port => 25,
    :domain => 'example.com',
    # These are custom to OUR setup - used later in the code 
    :default_from => 'it.systems@example.com',
    :default_notify => ["it.manager@example.com"],
    :default_signature => "
---------------------------
This is an automatic email.
If you have any questions please contact customer service 
at 1 (800) 888-0000 or go to http://www.example.com.
Thank you for your business!" 

  }



end
```

So is this a good approach? Or is there a better way then these two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track for default_from and default_notify.
I wouldn't use SMTP settings for that; those aren't SMTP settings, they're just general mailer settings.

I'd go with something like this in an initializer:

```
MAILER_SETTINGS = YAML::load(open(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "mailer.yml")).read)[Rails.env]
```

With a yaml file that looks like this:

```
development: &development
  default_from: foo@bar.com
  default_notify: ["foo@bar.com"]  

production:
  <<: *development
  default_from: production@bar.com
```

That lets you set defaults, then cascade them down and override per-environment as desired.

However, for the signature, I'd just move that into a partial, which you then include in your mail templates. They're views like any other and can have layouts, partials, and all of that.